# Extreme long runtime for "rf" using Caret package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am training a model using `rf` from the `caret` package using R (and Rstudio). The training data set is a data frame with 76k rows and 291 cols. My code is as follows:

```
library(caret)

myTrControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                            number = 5,
                            repeats = 3,
                            p = 0.75,
                            classProbs = TRUE,
                            summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

set.seed(64)
myRF <- train(x = myTrain[ , -c(1, 291)],
              y = myTrain$TARGET,
              data = myTrain,
              method = "rf",
              metric = "ROC",
              maximize = TRUE,
              trControl = myTrControl)
```

It's been running for 24 hours now. Is there a way I can estimate how long it will take?

I read the `caret` documentation and I should probably have set `verboseIter = TRUE` in `trainControl` to get some information of what's going on while it calculates. I guess there is no "while calculating" way to request information of the progress, right?

And third question: are there any other parameters within `trainControl` and `train` that I should regularly use to get information of the calculation while it's in progress?

Thanks!

Comment: Sessioninfo() would be more helpful to distinguishing the problem. Your feature set is very large and you may want to do some [feature selection](http://www.r-bloggers.com/feature-selection-using-the-caret-package/). If you are set on running with all those features maybe try [rfcv function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomforest/docs/rfcv) in random forests. Although, I still believe this will take awhile without feature selection. Cheers, Cody

Comment: Thanks Cody. I did feature selection to get down to this number, but it's true, I could still apply `rfcv` from the `randomForest` package to do feature selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's taking it's time because of some factors, outside the 76k records and 291 cols.

Your settings are a 5 fold cv repeating 3 times, but since no grid is specified the tunelength option in train is being used. This has a default op 3. What happens now is that you have 5 fold cv repeated 3 times, with a tuning of 3 different values of mtry. So in total it will train 5*3*3 = 45 training sessions + of course 45 times testing on the holdout. After this it will do 1 final training set on the full training set based on the selection of the tuning parameters after the cv.

And further answering your questions:

1. The only way to estimate this is to run your model on a different machine and set evertything to 1, (repeatedcv, number = 1, repeat = 1, and in train, tunelength = 1) That gives you a base estimate.
2. correct
3. verboseIter is the way to go.